# How to correctly store in the answers table?

Tags: php

The participant array has this structure:

```
array:1 [▼
  "participant" => array:2 [▼
    1 => array:5 [▼
      "name" => "John"
      "surname" => "W"
      "answer" => array:6 [▼
        0 => "text answer"
        1 => "long answer"
        2 => "check1"
        3 => "rb1"
        4 => "selectmenu1"
        5 => "img.jpg"
      ]
      "question_id" => array:6 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "2"
        2 => "3"
        3 => "4"
        4 => "5"
        5 => "6"
      ]
      "rtypes" => "1"
    ]
    2 => array:3 [▼
      "name" => "Jake"
      "surname" => "K"
      "rtypes" => "4"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Each index of the array have data about a participant that is being registered in a confernece. In this case, the participant in index "1" of the array has the name "John" and surname "w" and is being registered in the registration type with id "1". This registration type has 6 custom questions associated with it, so in the registratin form the user that is doing the registration answer to this custom questions and the answers are stored in the "answer" array.

The participant in index "2" of the array dont have answers because he is being registered in the registration type with id 4, this registration type with id 4 dont have any custom question associated, so in the registration form, was only collected the name and surname from this participant, there are no answers for this participant.

**Doubt: How to store the answers of each participant in the answers table**

Now I want to store the info of each participant in the participants table and also the answers of each participant in the answers table. The code to store in the participants table its working fine.

But to store each answer is not working because the answer and question_id are arrays. Do you know how to properly store in the answers table each answer and question_id?

```
foreach ($participants['participant'] as $k => $participant) {
    $name = $participant['name'];
    $surname = $participant['surname'];

    $participant_result = Participant::create([
        'name' => $name,
        'surname' => $surname,
        'registration_id' => $registration->id,
        'registration_type_id' => $participant['rtypes']
    ]);

    //var_dump($participant['question_id']);
    // the error is here
    // store each answer of each participant that has answers
    if (isset($participant['question_id'])) {
        $answer = Answer::create([
            'question_id' => $participant['question_id'],
            'participant_id' => $participant_result->id,
            'answer' => $participant['answer'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try creating a dummy variable that you know is an array and pass it in to check its not something else. In the future, however, you'd be much better off using PHP objects, it makes work like this much more simple. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: Don’t you need to add six answers?

Comment: yes, is necessary to insert each answer in the answers array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create one Answer for each, well, answer.  I’ve only added a loop and some array indices to your code.

```
if (isset($participant['question_id'])) {
  for ($i=0; $i < count($participant["question_id"]); $i++) {
    $answer = Answer::create([
        'question_id' => $participant['question_id'][$i],
        'participant_id' => $participant_result->id,
        'answer' => $participant['answer'][$i]
    ]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, like that is not storing properly in the answers table, I updated the question to show the issue.

Comment: This code will create one database row per answer.  I disagree with jamming six answers into one row because it violates [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form), and will make queries based on this data extremely difficult.